# How to manage/update a setInterval using Express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, setinterval

So, I want to have an endpoint using express to start something like a setInterval (running a task every X ms), another to stop it. It doesn't have to be setInterval but I don't know what else to use.
How can I manage to do that ? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setTimeout` too.

```
function doSomething() {
    console.log("10 seconds");
    setTimeout(doSomething, 10000);
}

setTimeout(doSomething, 10000);
```

There is method to stop it `clearTimeout()`

Comment: How can I persist this task ? For exemple in my database